# How do I highlight the edge arrow with yFiles for JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, yfiles

I am using yFiles for JavaFX and I need to highlight directed edges and their arrows. I am using `HighlightIndicatorManager<IModelItem>.addHighlight(IModelItem)` but it only highlights the edge line and leaves its arrow without highlight. Is it possible to highlight the arrows of edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.

The default edge-highlight only highlights the path of the edge, no matter what labels, arrow heads, or stroking is used.

You may use utility class [`EdgeStyleDecorationInstaller`](http://docs.yworks.com/yfilesjavafx/doc/api/#/api/com.yworks.yfiles.view.EdgeStyleDecorationInstaller) to wrap any `IEdgeStyle` implementation for use with the highlighting. In order to obtain a colored arrow head you can do this:

```
IArrow arrow = new Arrow(ArrowType.DEFAULT, orangePen, Color.ORANGE, 0, 1);
```

And then use the [HighlightDecorator](http://docs.yworks.com/yfilesjavafx/doc/api/#/api/com.yworks.yfiles.graph.EdgeDecorator#EdgeDecorator-property-HighlightDecorator) to apply different or dynamic highlights to the various edges in your graph.

The yFiles evaluation package contains a sample of this technique in the "GraphViewerApplication" in `GraphViewerController#initializeHighlighting`.